# How to make content appear under absolute position

Tags: html, css

I have a web page, all works as expected. I've been giving a "control" (based upon javascript) but it won't work even with the HTML and CSS! So to keep this to the point, I've left the JavaScript out of the question.

```
<!-- start js control-->
<div style="position:relative;">
<div style="position:absolute;">
asdf
</div>
<div style="position:absolute;">
asdf2222
</div>
</div>

<!--rest of web page-->
<div>
here is content
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5zpz4eys/

As you can see in the fiddle, the issue is the text overlaps. I think it's because the absolute doesn't have a height although within the relative position outer div.

In the fiddle, I've left off most of the actual CSS as I want to understand it at this level. What CSS do I need to add... What I expect to see is 3 lines:

```
asdf
asf222
here is content
```

Or, I expect to see 2 lines, where asdf and asdf22 are actually overlayed.

How can I do this?

Comment: Without positioning this can't be done. Changing the 'absolute' to 'relative' in your divs fixes it however. Why do you need absolute positioned divs when you want the behavior of relative positioned divs?

Comment: The inner has to be absolute as of the complex layout. there are many images over lapping etc and many child divs @rsn. maybe I can achieve this with relative position...

Comment: you could wrap the whole thing in an absolute/fixed positioned div. Why does the inner have to be absolute exactly?

Comment: @rsn, it doesn't... it was easier to make the layout that way... right, relative is the answer, please move to an answer:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use relative positioning for the inner divs, wrap them in an absolute/fixed positioned div.

Comment: Are you able to provide an example of wrapping them in abosolute/fixed position?

Comment: thanks for replying but your example shows the absolute box ontop of the content. I'd like the content to be after that absolute box?

Comment: That's not how the concept of absolute/fixed positioning works (http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).